# How to use MediaWiki API in C# in Windows 8 app

Tags: c#, windows-8.1, mediawiki-api

I'm attempting to create an app to allow users to view a wiki and, eventually, edit the wiki from their mobile devices. Because I'm a little more comfortable with it, I'm attempting first with a Windows 8.1 app. However, I know very little regarding the MediaWiki API, which the wiki uses. I know that the Windows 8 Wikipedia app does it, but in JS, which I don't understand.

My question is, how would the app, which I'm coding in C#, access the content, namely, text, images, and links, from the wiki?

Answer (score 0):

Use a [web API library for your framework](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Client_code#.NET).